# Custom select box in drupal

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

What is the best way to create a custom select box in drupal?

Structure in drupal:

```
<div>
  <label></label>
   <select>
     <option></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I want to change a design of select box.

Comment: What do you plan on using the select box for?

Comment: how do you want to create it? in the UI or using PHP ?

Comment: I want to change a design of select box.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make custom forms (including select boxes) in Drupal is to either use the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) or [Entity Forms](https://drupal.org/project/entityform%E2%80%8E) module. These modules allow you to create all the fields you need, store submission data, send notification emails, and more.